# How to access an Open Finn Application via selenium which is basically chromium based desktop application

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, openfin

We have an application which is chromium based but on Open Finn application

-The application is launched by clicking on the application shortcut which makes use of Open Finn RVM and Config.json file

-I want to launch this application via selenium.
-This application is chromium based desktop app but we are able inspect elements on this application which can be used to get the xpath of the application.

I am not able to get how to launch this application via selenium and chrome driver please help how to access this app

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoEqF.png)

Application shortcut Target:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\OpenFin\OpenFinRVM.exe --config="https://abc2.abc.com:1798/config/manifest.fin.json"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.